# Flask form submitting error

Tags: python, forms, flask

I have a form like this:

```
    <form method="post" action="/addReceiverHandler" id="addReceiverForm">
        <label for="title">name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="name"/><br>
        <label for="dimmer">Dimmer:</label>
        <input type="text" name="dimmer" value="True"/><br>
        <input type="submit" value="sync" />
    </form>
```

And I recive the answer with:

```
@app.route('/addReceiverHandler', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def addReceiverHandler():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        print request.form
```

But the strange thing is that the input field "title" arrives with value "name" but that's it. The second input does not arrive, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! Stupid hidden jQuery.

I had set a preventDefault behaviour in jQuery and submitting that way, seems like I've forgotten that...